# Send a message to client with Jersey

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I'm working on a Jersey application.
I have no problem using it when the client asks something to my server (by a button/click). But now I would like to add a button "loading" while some sql requests are executing. It's usually the client who asks something and then server send something but this time I need the server to send something, is it possible to do that ?

I have a list of jobs defined by an id, a name... and I added a @Transient load. I need to show a load GIF when load=true and nothing when load=false.

Extract of my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_JOB")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqJob", sequenceName = "SEQ_JOB", initialValue = 1,
        allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Job{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqJob", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "T_JOB_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Transient
    private boolean load;

}
```

Here is my function changing load value:

```
public void execute(){
   job.setLoad(true);
   // some functions taking few seconds/minuts...
   job.setLoad(false);
}
```

How can I communicate to my client value of job dynamically ?

I tried something like that with Jersey:

```
@POST
@Path("/getLoad")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean getLoad() {
    return load;
}
```

Service:

```
srv.getLoad = function(){
    return $http.post(baseService + 'getLoad');
}
 return srv;
```

And then in JS:

```
Services.getLoad().success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.load = data;

            });
```

PROBLEM: It works but I need to update/click to get value of load. I know I can use a setInterval but it would be horrible to do that ! Some one has an idea ? Thank you a lot !

Comment: Looks like nobady knows... Or maybe my explanation are bad ?

Comment: I was reading your post and frankly speaking, I couldn't get what exactly you are trying to ask